# UIButton takes up its own size Autolayout

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

What I tried was this :-

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(bringUpNextViewController:) 
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
[btn setTitle:@"8" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

NSLog(@"button size : %@", NSStringFromCGSize(btn.frame.size));
```

As output, I get this :

```
button size : {30, 29}
```

Then I gave `setTitle` string as nothing. The button width was still 30.

So why is this the case always?

I also tried giving a `high compression resistance priority` and `high content hugging priority`. Doesn't shrink to nothing.

The problem is also the fact that I want to reduce the width of the button simply based on its content, without giving any fixed width.

I could take the width of text and give the button the width, but I shouldn't be needing to do that either if the button was taking up the content width.

EDIT:

Its not the insets either which is causing the width to be `30`. Ghost value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A button is made of several subviews. It's very likely that the internal layout of a button has some default padding between the label and the button view itself.

Making a button like yours and examining the constraints shows the following:

```
button constraints (
"<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x8c40a60 H:[UIButton:0x8f29840(30)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>",
"<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x8c55280 V:[UIButton:0x8f29840(29)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>"
)
```

The 30 and 29 tie up with the size values you are seeing. The intrinsic content size property of the button also returns 30,29. Basically this is the minimum size for a button, in the absence of anything else.

It's not quite clear what you want or why you are bothered by this. Anything smaller will be a poor touch target, and a button with no label or image will be invisible anyway. If you add a longer title, the button will get bigger. If you add other constraints to force particular sizes, then these will override the intrinsic content size.

If you want the button to become invisible when it has no title, then you should explicitly hide it. This makes your intentions in the code much clearer and will prevent the user from accidentally hitting a button they can't really see.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Sounds alright now. But as I mentioned in the question, `The problem is also the fact that I want to reduce the width of the button simply based on its content, without giving any fixed width.` And `30` for a default content size seemed a tad too big, I just didn't want the button to appear at all. That would be better.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 the Apple HIG states that the minimum touch area of a button should be 44x44 points in size. 30 is already too small for a button to make it easily tappable. Reducing its size even further doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hiding the button would be better than relying on layout in that case. You could do this pretty easily at the point you set the title.

Comment: For this particular case, I have other buttons laid out next to it (i.e., to its right), so I want to pull them together. So I was just relying on the button size to do that. And writing all that layout code to do that... hassle. That's what I meant by `tad too big`. Give me nothing instead would be better.

Comment: Ah! I see. In that case you could manually add a zero width constraint to the button when you want to hide it and then remove the constraint when you want to show it again.

Comment: Yeah better I guess. Btw, wondering if I have missed something. Is there a way to override a given constraint (i.e., change it later), apart from storing the constraint in a variable, or if you haven't stored it as such, iterate through all of them constraints, find, remove, and rewrite the constraint.

Comment: Storing constraints in properties is usually the best bet. For your particular requirement then explicitly setting a width constraint to zero would be the simplest, as @Fogmeister suggests. You'd still need to take into account any insets between the buttons, though

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if there is a minimum intrinsic content size for a uibutton?

Anyway, try doing...

```
[button invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
```

Comment: Huh? Oh... I must have ticked it by mistake. Lol! Was on my iPad when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `[button sizeToFit];`?

For custom buttons, I think that you will need to override:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size;
```

Finally, if nothing other works, you can always try giving the button width from the text size like so

```
CGSize textsize = [yourText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]]; 
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,textsize.width, textsize.height)];
```

Comment: Couple of points. a) I am using `Autolayout` (no frame world). b) `sizeWithFont` is deprecated. Need to use `boundingRectWithSize` for that (future proof).

Comment: And I am using the width of the text finally, using autolayout. This is just Apple related stuff.

Comment: Ok. These methods are not very compatible with autolayout, but I will get back to you if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

First define a constraint for button size in storyboard.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonSizeConst;
```

After that you can set it's size to whatever you want like this.

```
self.buttonSizeConst.constant = 65.0;
```

[image]

Edit: With this method you need to calculate your button width but I think you don't want to do that. You need to autoresize UIButton for it's content. For this you should give constraints like image below. It will expand to right when you change your title.

[image]

Comment: Its Apple related stuff. Wondering where that "30" came from. I know this method already.